# SQL Server : FOR XML converting integer columns as float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view in SQL Server with a mixture of `INTEGER`, `STRING` and `DECIMAL` columns.
When I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM [VIEW] 
FOR XML RAW
```

the `INTEGER` and `DECIMAL` columns get incorrectly converted to a scientific notation value like `2.400000000000000e+001` where it should be simply `24` for the integer column.

If I manually convert the column like

```
CAST([column] AS VARCHAR(128))
```

then this doesn't happen. But what if I only know the name of this one column and the remaining numerical values need to be `DECIMAL(32, 10)`?

Comment: If you don't know the names of the columns that are present in the view, you will have to use Dynamic SQL for that. You could use the query as a basis here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000999/how-to-list-the-source-table-name-of-columns-in-a-view-sql-server-2005

Comment: First you say there are integer columns in your view and then you say you have only  one integer column and you end with a requirement that the rest should be decimal. Your question is somewhat confusing. So how is it really? What data type does the columns actually have in your view?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 
I have only one column as INT and the rest columns can be a mixture of STRINGS and DECIMAL(32, 10)

Comment: I modified the original question to help make better sense

Comment: The only way to avoid this was by actually casting each numeric column inside the SELECT statement of the view. After I SELECT the view, then the columns are correctly formatted.