# List Source Table Name from multiple databases in View (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server

I want to find out all the source table name for the columns in a view in SQL server 2014.

I know this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000999/how-to-list-the-source-table-name-of-columns-in-a-view-sql-server-2005) but my problem is my view uses tables from multiple databases.

Things that I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE AS cu
JOIN    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
ON      c.TABLE_SCHEMA  = cu.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND     c.TABLE_CATALOG = cu.TABLE_CATALOG
AND     c.TABLE_NAME    = cu.TABLE_NAME
AND     c.COLUMN_NAME   = cu.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE   cu.VIEW_NAME    = '<your view name>'
AND     cu.VIEW_SCHEMA  = '<your view schema>'
```

This only gives column and table name from current database. I need something similar but from all the databases used in my view.

Feel free to ask questions if I am not clear.

Comment: You'll have to go dynamic - each database has its own schema views,  but any particular query can only reference a fixed set of tables/views itself. I'd query whether its worth the work versus just opening the view definition.

Comment: I have to go through lots of views and fetch column information like data type, table name, is nullable etc. Its a lot of work. I was hoping to create a query that can do the job.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Any pointer on how can I do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried dynamic SQL ? this shoudl resolve your issue 
also please get back to me on this [Weeks that overlap a year SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135715/weeks-that-overlap-a-year-sql/32136127?noredirect=1#comment52163224_32136127)