# Weeks that overlap a year SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio, datetime, week-number, product-quantity

I'm currently working on a huge report and need some help on a vital part which I've been on for ironically weeks

I have a report that calculates quantity based on a few things 
but what im trying to do is when the "PREQuantity" column is null and week of year = 1 then get quanitity from week of year 52 for the previous year 
the case statement is unfinished i know, but essentially i need the report to force in week 52 of the previous year for the prequantity

```
SELECT DR.DivNo
    ,p.[ProductCode]
    ,p.ProductClass
    ,p.EmpNo
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,dr.Retail
    ,bd.[Buying Director]
INTO #Product
FROM [PRODUCT] p
LEFT JOIN [DIVRETAIL] DR ON p.ProductCode = DR.ProductCode
LEFT JOIN vwAllBuyingDirectors bd ON p.EmpNo = bd.bd_BuyingDirector
WHERE dr.ValidTo IS NULL
    AND dr.DivNo NOT LIKE '8__'
GROUP BY DR.DivNo
    ,p.[ProductCode]
    ,p.ProductClass
    ,p.EmpNo
    ,bd.[Buying Director]
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,dr.Retail

    --select * from #Product

SELECT  [Datetime]
    ,[FirstDayOfWeek]
    ,[FirstDayOfMonth]
    ,c.YearWeek
    ,s.NoOfStores
    ,s.DivNo
INTO #stores
FROM [Calendar] c
LEFT JOIN Stores s ON c.FirstDayOfMonth = s.Validfrom
WHERE c.[Datetime] = firstdayofweek

--- GIVE STORE COUNT TO EACH DATETIME
SELECT s.DivNo
    ,c.[Datetime]
    ,c.WeekofYear
    ,c.FirstdayofWeek
    ,c.YearWeek
    ,s.NoOfStores
INTO #weeklystores
FROM .Calendar c
LEFT JOIN #stores s ON c.FirstDayOfWeek = s.FirstDayOfWeek
 -- Join numbers from #stores according to first day of week.  Each week onmly has the first day of the week's store count as a reference.

------------------------------------------PREVIOUS WEEK---------------------     --------------------
 SELECT  [Datetime]
    ,[FirstDayOflastWeek]
    ,[FirstDayOflastMonth]
    ,c.YearWeek
    ,s.NoOfStores
    ,s.DivNo
INTO #storesv2
FROM [Calendar] c
LEFT JOIN Stores s ON c.FirstDayOfMonth = s.Validfrom
WHERE c.[Datetime] = FirstDayOfWeek

--- GIVE STORE COUNT TO EACH DATETIME
SELECT s.DivNo
    ,c.[Datetime]
    ,c.WeekofYear
    ,c.FirstdayoflastWeek
    ,c.YearWeek
    ,s.NoOfStores
INTO #preweeklystores
FROM .Calendar c
LEFT JOIN #storesv2 s ON c.FirstDayOfWeek = s.FirstDayOfLastWeek    

/*
ASSIGN STORE COUNTS AND WEEK NUMBERS TO POS DATA
*/
    CREATE TABLE #salescore (
    [DivNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[ProductCode] INT
    ,[Description] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[CGNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[SCGNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,Retail DECIMAL(38, 2)
    ,[WeekOfYear] TINYINT
    ,FirstDayOfWeek DATETIME
    ,[Quantity] INT
    ,[Sales] DECIMAL(38, 2)
    ,[NoOfStores] INT
    ,[USW] DECIMAL(38, 0)
    )

INSERT INTO #salescore
SELECT pos.DivNo
    ,pos.ProductCode
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,p.Retail
    ,w.WeekOfYear
    ,w.FirstDayOfWeek
    ,Sum(Quantity) [Quantity]
    ,sum(pos.Retail) [Retail2]
    ,w.NoOfStores
    ,(Sum(Quantity) / w.NoOfStores) USW
FROM .pos pos
LEFT JOIN #weeklystores w ON pos.PosDate = w.[DATETIME]
LEFT JOIN #Product p ON p.ProductCode = pos.ProductCode
    AND p.DivNo = pos.DivNo
    AND pos.DivNo = w.DivNo
WHERE pos.DivNo NOT LIKE '8__' /* Get rid of IRL Regions */
and w.YearWeek >2013
    and w.YearWeek IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM DataWarehouse.dbo.ufnSplit(@YEAR, ',')
        )
    AND p.EmpNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@BD, ',')
        )
    AND p.CGNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM .ufnSplit(@CGNo, ',')
        )
    AND p.SCGNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@SCGNo, ',')
        )
    AND p.ProductClass IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@ProductClass, ',')
        )
    AND p.ProductCode IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@ProductCode, ',')
        )
    AND pos.DivNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@Region, ',')
        )
    AND w.WeekOfYear IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@WOY, ',')
        )
    AND w.WeekOfYear IS NOT NULL /* Get rid of pos before goldthorp opening day */
GROUP BY pos.DivNo
    ,pos.ProductCode
    ,w.WeekOfYear
    ,w.NoOfStores
    ,w.FirstDayOfWeek
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,p.Retail


    ----------------------------------------PreviousWeekSales---------------------------------------------

        CREATE TABLE #presales (
    [DivNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[ProductCode] INT
    ,[Description] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[CGNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[SCGNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,Retail DECIMAL(38, 2)
    ,PrevWOY TINYINT
    ,FirstDayOfWeek DATETIME
    ,[PreQuantity] INT
    ,[Sales] DECIMAL(38, 2)
    ,[NoOfStores] INT
    ,[USW] DECIMAL(38, 0)
    )

INSERT INTO #presales
SELECT pos.DivNo
    ,pos.ProductCode
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,p.Retail
    ,w.WeekOfYear as PrevWOY
    ,w.FirstDayOfLastWeek
    ,SUM(Quantity) Quantity
    ,sum(pos.Retail) [Retail3]
    ,w.NoOfStores
    ,(Sum(Quantity) / w.NoOfStores) USW
FROM .pos pos
LEFT JOIN #preweeklystores w ON pos.PosDate = w.[DATETIME]
LEFT JOIN #Product p ON p.ProductCode = pos.ProductCode
    AND p.DivNo = pos.DivNo
    AND pos.DivNo = w.DivNo
WHERE pos.DivNo NOT LIKE '8__' /* Get rid of IRL Regions */
and w.YearWeek >2013
    and w.YearWeek IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM .ufnSplit(@YEAR, ',')
        )
    AND p.EmpNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@BD, ',')
        )
    AND p.CGNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@CGNo, ',')
        )
    AND p.SCGNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@SCGNo, ',')
        )
    AND p.ProductClass IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@ProductClass, ',')
        )
    AND p.ProductCode IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@ProductCode, ',')
        )
    AND pos.DivNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM ufnSplit(@Region, ',')
        )
    --AND w.WeekOfYear IN (
    --  SELECT Item
    --  FROM ufnSplit(@WOY, ',')
    --  )
    AND w.WeekOfYear IS NOT NULL /* Get rid of pos before goldthorp opening day */
GROUP BY pos.DivNo
    ,pos.ProductCode
    ,w.WeekOfYear
    ,w.NoOfStores
    ,w.FirstDayOfLastWeek
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,p.Retail



    CREATE TABLE #sales (
    [DivNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[ProductCode] INT
    ,[Description] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[CGNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,[SCGNo] NVARCHAR(max)
    ,Retail DECIMAL(38, 2)
    ,[WeekOfYear] TINYINT
    ,FirstDayOfWeek DATETIME
    ,[PreQuantity] int
    ,[Quantity] INT
    ,[Sales] DECIMAL(38, 2)
    ,[NoOfStores] INT
    ,[USW] DECIMAL(38, 0)
    ) 
    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT pos.DivNo
    ,pos.ProductCode
    ,p.Description
    ,p.CGNo
    ,p.SCGNo
    ,p.Retail
    ,pos.WeekOfYear
    ,pos.FirstDayOfWeek
    ,SUM(ps.PreQuantity)
    ,Sum(pos.Quantity) [Quantity]
    ,sum(pos.Sales) Sales
    ,pos.NoOfStores
    ,(Sum(pos.Quantity) / pos.NoOfStores) USW
FROM #salescore pos
LEFT JOIN #presales PS on (pos.WeekOfYear -1) = ps.PrevWOY and pos.ProductCode = ps.ProductCode and pos.DivNo= ps.DivNo

LEFT JOIN #Product p ON p.ProductCode = pos.ProductCode
    AND p.DivNo = pos.DivNo
WHERE pos.DivNo NOT LIKE '8__' /* Get rid of IRL Regions */
Group By
    pos.DivNo
    ,pos.ProductCode
    ,p.Description
    ,p.CGNo
    ,p.SCGNo
    ,p.Retail
    ,pos.WeekOfYear
    ,pos.FirstDayOfWeek
    ,pos.NoOfStores






SELECT *
FROM #Sales

ORDER BY 3 ASC

DROP TABLE #weeklystores
DROP TABLE #stores
DROP TABLE #storesv2
DROP TABLE #sales
DROP TABLE #Product
END
```

i made this change as suggested by @Abhay

```
 ,case when Sum(PreQuantity)= null and pos.WeekOfYear = 1 then (Select        Sum(PreQuantity) from #presales where WeekOfYear =52 and @year = @Year-1) else       SUM(PreQuantity) end as quantity
```

it didnt work

[image]

After Changes

[image]

Comment: is the above output for the query you have mentioned? you are using aggregate functions along with non aggregated columns without specifying a group by.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to complete your case statement based on what I understand:

```
case when Sum(PreQuantity)= null and WeekOfYear = 1 then 
(Select Sum(Quantity)= null from Sometable a where a.WeekOfYear =52 and a.year = Year-1) 
else null end
```

Note:
Assuming you have a column or can derive a column for year

Sometable can be many tables joined together from where you can calculate sum(quantity)

(Year)-1 will come from your original outer query i.e

```
FROM pos pos
LEFT JOIN #preweeklystores w ON pos.PosDate = w.[DATETIME]
LEFT JOIN #Product p ON p.ProductCode = pos.ProductCode
    AND p.DivNo = pos.DivNo
    AND pos.DivNo = w.DivNo
WHERE pos.DivNo NOT LIKE '8__' /* Get rid of IRL Regions */
and w.YearWeek >2013
```

If you can use alias for tablename as prefix for each column, I would be able to give a exact query. Also, do you have a column for date/year?

Comment: i will paste my whole stored proc

Comment: You can try using subquery in case statement. It should solve your problem.

Comment: could you show me what you mean ive pasted my whole query @AbhayChauhan

Comment: this didnt work 
case when Sum(PreQuantity)= null and pos.WeekOfYear = 1 then (Select Sum(Quantity) from #presales where WeekOfYear =52 and @year = @Year-1) else SUM(Quantity) end as quantity

Comment: @JamesChaggar `@year =@year-1` is not making sense. Just try to put values in it. It won't be true ever. E.g. 2015=2015-1 won't be true. You should use a column if it is available in your tables.

Comment: this did not work 
,case when Sum(PreQuantity)= null and pos.WeekOfYear = 1 then (Select Sum(PreQuantity) from #presales where WeekOfYear =52 and YearWeek = YearWeek-1) else SUM(PreQuantity) end as quantity

Comment: If I am not wrong this case is for prequantity. Try this: `case when Sum(PreQuantity)= null and pos.WeekOfYear = 1 then (Select Sum(Quantity) from #presales where WeekOfYear =52 and YearWeek = YearWeek-1) else SUM(PreQuantity) end as Prequantity`. Assuming you need to show `sum(quantity)` of last year's week 52 when prequantity is null for 1st week of current year.

Comment: this had the same output of null

Comment: Sorry, I am tied up with my work. So not able to re-create your scenario and give you a working query. Can you please create required tables and insert sample data and create this scenario on SQLFiddle. I should be able to help you there.