# Inner join is resulting in cartesian product. How to resolve this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We're using Azure Synapse and I'm trying to list the column aliases in a given VIEW and their corresponding original columns from their respective Tables used in the VIEW. But I keep getting cartesian product for any given view. Not sure how I can solve this.

```
 SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT IVT.view_name,
               IVT.table_name,
               IVC.column_name
        FROM   (SELECT vt.view_name,
                       vt.table_name
                FROM   information_schema.view_table_usage vt) IVT
               INNER JOIN (SELECT vc.view_name,
                                  column_name,
                                  table_name
                           FROM   information_schema.view_column_usage vc) IVC
                       ON IVT.view_name = IVC.view_name) t1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT NAME      AS view_column_name,
                          object_id AS column_object_id,
                          cols.view_object_id,
                          cols.view_name,
                          cols.table_name
                   FROM   sys.columns c
                          INNER JOIN (SELECT object_id AS view_object_id,
                                             IVT.view_name,
                                             IVT.table_name
                                      FROM   sys.views v
                                             INNER JOIN
                                             information_schema.view_table_usage
                                             IVT
                                                     ON v.NAME = IVT.view_name)
                                     cols
                                  ON c.object_id = cols.view_object_id) t2
               ON ( t1.table_name = t2.table_name
                    AND t1.view_name = t2.view_name )
```

The two query parts `t1` and `t2` are themselves returning correct output individually. But the moment I perform a join between them, it ends up in a cartesian product.

Comment: All John and A means the join conditions are always true. Add some other names and departments to the sample data and you'll see a difference-

Comment: Well, your tables only have a single department name `A` and a single employee name `John`. So of course the join condition `(t1.dept = t2.dept and t1.emp_name = t2.emp)` matches for every combination of rows ...

Comment: Furhtermore it seems, both your tables are holding the exact same information. The only difference is, that for `table_2` the language is abbreviated. If you want only three rows out of this query, you probably need some matching criterion for the language as well. I'd say, instead of trying to fiddle around with this query to get your desired result, you should think about your datamodel first (try reading a bit about *database normalization*)

Comment: So for you data here, you should ask yourself, what determines the `language` in a table row? Is it the department? Is it the employee? Is it the combination of both. Furhtermore I'd suggest that table_1 and table_2 both only hold a language code (which you can then add to the join condition) and you have a separate table of language names, which you can join to get the language name for the code

Comment: I think it's a poorly simulated example from me. My actual query is with the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables and views and columns where I face this cartesian product. I'm trying to identify the columns in a given VIEW and their corresponding columns from their respective tables.

Comment: Perhaps you should be showing us the query you *actually* have then. If you are using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` then the problem is very likely your query, not the data (objects).

Comment: in that case maybe this question will have the answers you seek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000999/how-to-list-the-source-table-name-of-columns-in-a-view-sql-server-2005

Comment: @ThomA - I've updated my question and provided the actual query that I'm using.

Comment: The formatting of this just makes my head spin. Indentation and white space are your friends.

Comment: @BartMcEndree - Almost. But the query in that answer also gives the column names as present in their tables. But what I seek is the column aliases in the VIEW alongside their original column names from the tables. And that I do not seem to get. I updated my question above with the query I'm using.

Comment: @SeanLange - Sorry, an amateur here. Thanks for pointing out though. I just updated the formatted version of the query.

Comment: I dont think what you're asking for is possible, other than in the trivial case where the columns are aliased as themselves. `view_column_usage` lists underlying table columns used in the view,  but there's no way to know what they're aliased as. Plus, a view field could be an alias of no columns (constant, function) one column, or multiple columns (if the expression uses more than one) there just isn't enough data in simple metadata tables to programmatically map that.

Comment: But to your original question, if you're trying to pair up used view columns with actual table columns, at some point you're going to have to join on some semblance of column name. I see joins on view name and table name, but nothing related to fields/columns

Comment: Agree with @Xedni. You are not going to find a mapping between source table columns and resulting view columns in INFORMATION_SCHEMA. There are just too many variations. A view column might be (1) A direct table column reference, (2) an aliased table column reference, (3) A reference to a subquery result. (4) A simple aggregation of a table or subquery column. (5) A constant. (6) Any combination of the preceding in an expression of arbitrarily complexity, including expressions in nested subqueries and maybe other views. It would take complex expression tree parsing to extract the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try this at home, but you can sometimes get parts of this information by following:

```sql
exec sys.sp_describe_first_result_set N'
select *
from some_view_which_doesnt_use_weird_things for browse'
```

The `for browse` thing is the magic sauce that makes sql server return some extra information like table / column name, it's mostly used for recordset work and stuff like datagrids that process one record at a time.

It won't work with all views, and sometimes you get some extra columns (this is the downside of FOR BROWSE), but sometimes it works.

You can loop your view names, call this procedure and gather info you need.

Comment: No need to loop, you can use `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` which is a Table Valued Function

Comment: The following combines `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` (filtered for views) with `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` to extract direct view-to-table column mappings. View columns that are not directly sourced from a table column, such as constants or expressions, will have null source values. [sample db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N2vrWmw3). @Charlieface - Feel free to tweak and include in your answer.

Comment: @TN That's almost the same as my answer already, but as I say "information_schema is for compatibility only and can be somewhat unreliable"

Comment: @Charlieface - Yes.  I was working on a tedious #temp table version for the sp_describe when I saw your function comment. I didn't see the other answer until after. But yes, virtually identical.

Comment: That's nice, you guys ruined my one cool trick with some standard parameters. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks to you guys, I just now discovered `sys.dm_tran_locks`, `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and lots of other good stuff.  I had long been capturing `sp_lock` and `sp_who` content via temp tables whenever I needed to figure out what processes have gone rogue. Wish I had known about those 20 years ago.

Comment: Don't think those dm-views existed 20 years ago @TN! when i started, sp_who2 was the king, but someone wrote a really nice sp_who3 that could display the query text. Good times =)

Answer (score 2):

A better option is the `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` system function, which can be used directly in a query.

```sql
select
  schema_name = s.name,
  view_name = v.name,
  column_name = r.name,
  r.source_database,
  r.source_schema,
  r.source_table,
  r.source_column
from sys.views v
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = v.schema_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
  N'SELECT v.* FROM ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(v.name) + ' v', NULL, 1
) r;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/MIYT77Xb)

---

The reason your existing query didn't work is simple: you had no join condition on the column.

Your query, cleaned up and simplified, is essentially this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.view_table_usage IVT
INNER JOIN information_schema.view_column_usage IVC ON IVT.view_name = IVC.view_name
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
  (
    INNER JOIN sys.views v ON c.object_id = v.view_object_id
    INNER JOIN information_schema.view_table_usage IVT2 ON v.NAME = IVT2.view_name
  )
  ON IVT2.table_name = IVT.table_name
  AND IVT2.view_name = IVT.view_name;
```

You would have needed an extra join condition `AND IVC.COLUMN_NAME = c.name`.

But it's still needlessly complicated with many unnecessary joins, and in any case `information_schema` is for compatibility only and can be somewhat unreliable.

Comment: I keep getting `Incorrect syntax near 'N'SELECT v.* FROM ''.` when I run the query with `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`. It works on dbfiddle but fails on my SSMS / Azure Synapse. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't say you were using Synapse, `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` isn't available for that I think.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the exact db system I'm using. I always get into this illusion of T-SQL being same on both on-prem SQL Server and its corresponding Azure flavours. I'm wrong!